# Visual Basic.NET Payscale w/ Menu's

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Basic.NET and I'm making a Payscale program for soccer referees where you type in what age you're reffing and it will you tell you how much you're making. Recreational soccer pays referees less, than Classic soccer does. I have a Rec and a Classic Menu. I made it so the code is automatically using the Rec payscale and when I click on the classic menu and type in an age to try to give me the updated pay it still gives me the Rec Pay. How can I make it so it will give me the classic payscale not the rec payscale when I click on that menu and then type in the age?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub txtanswer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtanswer.TextChanged
    If txtanswer.Text = "U8" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "$16"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U9" Or txtanswer.Text = "U10" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $20, AR - $10"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U11" Or txtanswer.Text = "U12" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $22, AR - $12"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U13" Or txtanswer.Text = "U14" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $24, AR - $14"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U15" Or txtanswer.Text = "U16" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $26, AR - $16"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U17" Or txtanswer.Text = "U18" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $30, AR - $20"
    End If
    End Sub

 Private Sub ClassicToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClassicToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If txtanswer.Text = "U11" Or txtanswer.Text = "U12" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $25, AR - $15"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U13" Or txtanswer.Text = "U14" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $30, AR - $18"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U15" Or txtanswer.Text = "U16" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $34, AR - $20"
    End If
    If txtanswer.Text = "U17" Or txtanswer.Text = "U18" Then
        lblanswer.Text = "Center - $38, AR - $22"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to change the way you treat the menustrip item.  Menus usually DO something, you want it to retain a selection to be evaluated.  So treat it like a checkbox in your click event:

```
  ClassicToolStripMenuItem.Checked = Not ClassicToolStripMenuItem.Checked
```

That will toggle the check state and allow you to test if the menu item is checked in your code.

**EDIT**

If you are using the MenuItem like a checkbox, you can:

```
If ClassicToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
   ' do classic calcs
   ... copy code from the menu click event
Else
   ' it is NOT checked
   ...use the code already in text changed
End If
```

Tips:

- Consider learning about SELECT CASE
- As I am typing "U11", "U" and "U1" match nothing so the previous result shows.  It might be better to consider a different entry method.
- Finally, "u11" isnt going to match and post a result either because "U11" <> "u11".  You might want to change the test. (look at the `String` methods).

Comment: I'm just learning VB.NET and I don't really understand that line of code. I assume the check boxes would be sort of like radio buttons in a way, but I don't see how that line of code can make it change the payscale.

Comment: Menu items can be checked as options: `.Checked`  is the property True or False telling whether it is checked.  The `Not` reverses the state of the check so it toggles on/off each time it clicks...add it to teh Click event of the menuitem and see.  Then move the big IF/ELSE block to the `.TextChanged` event and use the checked state to calc for Rec vs CLassic.